# React Native loop with map

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing an app in React Native and I have this JSON:

```
const places = {
  "place1":{
    "title":"title 1",
    "image":"../img/image1.jpeg",
    "description":"description 1.",
  },
  "place2":{
    "title":"title 2",
    "image":"../img/image2.jpeg",
    "description":"description 2.",
  }
};
```

I'd like to output it in a list of elements, I understood that to do this I have to use map() this is my code:

```
export default class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {places.map((place) => {
            return (
              <Text>{place.title}</Text>
              <Text>{place.description}</Text>
            )
         })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but it does not work, does anyone know what I'm wrong or how can I reach my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MAP function works on **Array**, not on object. Please update your const places as the following:

```
const places = [{
  "title":"title 1",
  "image":"../img/image1.jpeg",
  "description":"description 1.",
},{
 "title":"title 2",
 "image":"../img/image2.jpeg",
 "description":"description 2.",
}]
```

Thanks. Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 5):

Places is an object and you can't iterate like this. You have to get the keys with Object.keys and iterate through them instead. Like this.

```
Object.keys(places).map((key) => {
    return (
      <Text>{places[key].title}</Text>
      <Text>{places[key].description}</Text>
    )
 })}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Snack here at: https://snack.expo.io/rk4f3aSnQ with the solution.

`map` function belongs to the Array Class so won't work on an Object.

I put the object in `places.json` file in the project. You will surely find a way to do so.
Also, always `return` code as a single component while using `react-native` as you will notice in the `App.js` file this code snippet:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {places.map((place) =>
              <View>
                <Text>{place.title}</Text>
                <Text>{place.description}</Text>
              </View>)}
        </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the spread operator:

```
{[...places].map((place) => {
  return (
    <Text>{place.title}</Text>
    <Text>{place.description}</Text>
  )
})}
```